# Find all $P(x)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the functional equation $ (x + 1)P(x - 1) - (x - 1)P(x) = c $ holds.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, solution-verification

$\blacksquare~$ **Problem:** Find all $P(x)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the following functional equation holds
\begin{align*}
    (x + 1)P(x - 1) - (x - 1)P(x) = c
\end{align*}

---

---

$\blacksquare~$ **My Attempt:**

> We will check at first for $x = 0 \text{ and } -1$ and by some simple calculation we will obtain that
> \begin{align*}
>     P(0) = P( - 1) = \frac{c}{2}
> \end{align*}

Let's consider a polynomial $Q(x)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) = P(x) - \frac{c}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore our new functional equation becomes
\begin{align}
    &(x + 1)Q(x - 1) - (x - 1) Q(x) = 0\\
    \implies & (x + 1)Q(x - 1) = (x - 1) Q(x) \quad \quad \cdots\cdots (1)
\end{align}
Then we will make a claim about our new defined polynomial $Q(x)$.

> **Claim:** The polynomial $Q(x)$ follows the following conditions
> \begin{align*}
> Q ( x ) = \begin{cases} 
>   0 & \text{ if } Q \text{ is a constant polynomial in } \mathbb{R}[x] \\
>  b \cdot x ( x + 1 ) & \text{ otherwise and for some }b \in \mathbb{R} \\
>    \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

$\bullet~$ *Proof:* From the way we constructed $Q(x)$ we have
\begin{align*}
    Q(0) = Q(-1) = 0
\end{align*}
therefore let's consider the two cases separately

> $\bullet~$ **Case $1$:** We have $Q$ as a constant polynomial. Say for some $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$
> \begin{align*}
>         Q(x) \equiv a \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}
>     \end{align*}
> Then, we have for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$
> \begin{align*}
>         &a \cdot (x + 1) = a \cdot (x - 1)\\
>         \implies & ax + a = ax - a\\
>         \implies & a = 0
>     \end{align*}
> Hence the first part of our claim is proved.

> $\bullet~$ **Case $2$:** If $Q(x)$ is non-constant, then it's obvious that the polynomial $Q(x)$ has roots $0, -1,$ therefore,
> \begin{align*}
>         Q(x) = x(x + 1) M(x) \quad \text{for some polynomial } M(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]
>     \end{align*}
> such that $\text{deg}(Q) > \text{deg}(M)$.

> Therefore, we have from $(1)$
> \begin{align*}
>         \implies &(x - 1) \cdot x \cdot (x + 1) M(x - 1) = (x - 1) \cdot x \cdot (x + 1) M(x)\\
>         \implies & M(x - 1) = M(x) \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R} - \{-1, 0, 1\} 
>     \end{align*}
> Now on doing $x \mapsto x + 1$ we have
> \begin{align*}
>         M(x) = M(x + 1) \quad \text{and similarly for each map } ( x + j ) \mapsto \{x + (j + 1)\} 
>     \end{align*}
> Hence we have the conclusion
> \begin{align*}
>         &M(x) = M(x + 1) = M(x + 2) = \cdots = M(x + n) = \cdots\\
>         \implies & M(x) \equiv b \quad \text{for some }b \text{ in } \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \forall \text{  } x \in \mathbb{R} 
>     \end{align*}

again from the quotient form of $Q(x)$ we have
\begin{align*}
        Q(x) = b \cdot x(x + 1) \quad \text{for some } b \text{ in } \mathbb{R} 
    \end{align*}
Hence we have proved the second part of our claim too.

Therefore we have proved both our claims!

---

Hence we obatin that the polynomial $Q(x)$ precisely. Which implies that our polynomial $P(x)$ will be
\begin{align*}
P ( x ) = \begin{cases} 
  Q(x) + \frac{c}{2} = \frac{c}{2} & \text{ if } Q \text{ is a constant polynomial in } \mathbb{R}[x]\\ 
Q(x) + \frac{c}{2} =  b \cdot x ( x + 1 ) + \frac{c}{2} & \text{ otherwise and for some }b \in \mathbb{R} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Hence we are done!

---

Please check the solution, and please give some new ideas too :)

Comment: Final solution can be written just as $b \cdot x ( x + 1 ) + \frac{c}{2}$, you get the first case by $b=0$. Also see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1638091p10310922.

Comment: Also [determine all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $(x+1)P(x-1)-(x-1)P(x)$ is a constant polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727398)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [determine all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $(x+1)P(x-1)-(x-1)P(x)$ is a constant polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727398/determine-all-polynomials-px-such-that-x1px-1-x-1px-is-a-constant)